# Back/Forward mouse buttons don't show up in evtest

Tags: 20.04, mouse

My Mi Silent Mouse does not produce events when pressing the back/forward buttons. The mouse is connected via Bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04.1.

photo of side buttons
[image: .]

`$ xinput query-state "Mi Silent Mouse"` produces

```
2 classes :
ButtonClass
    button[1]=up
    button[2]=up
    button[3]=up
    button[4]=up
    button[5]=up
    button[6]=up
    button[7]=up
ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In
    valuator[0]=1973
    valuator[1]=741
    valuator[2]=0
    valuator[3]=11640
```

Buttons 1-5 are the three main buttons plus wheel up/down, so buttons 6-7 should be the back/forward buttons.

`evtest` doesn't show any events when pressing these two buttons though.

On the other hand, the mouse works perfectly on Windows on a secondary partition on the same machine.

I have not found much info on how to solve this problem, any help appreciated.

Comment: Does that mouse require its own driver from the mfg. to get all the buttons to work?

Comment: No, there are no drivers issued by the manufacturer for this mouse, for any OS.

Comment: Run `xev` and, in the white window that appears, try to hold down button 1 (left click) and, then (while holding it down), click with forward/backward buttons. See if you get a `ButtonPress` event (or post the logs).

Comment: Did you find anything out? I have the same issue.

Comment: I tracked down the error and found out the mouse gives out a bad report descriptor on USB. I wrote a fix, it's a kernel modue, I'll upload it soon.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse sends a bad HID report descriptor on Bluetooth (it sends the right one over USB). I wrote a kernel module to fix it: https://github.com/matega/hid_mimouse

Installation instructions:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/matega/hid_mimouse.git
cd hid_mimouse
make
```

If `make` runs without errors you can

```
sudo make install
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install hid_mimouse/1.0
```

And reboot.